# How to get value of snmp index outputs in TCL scripting language

Tags: if-statement, tcl

I need a script to find all disabled ports (ifAdminStatus=1) and un-shut them (or any other action)
The problem is I cannot get the value by if command. Seems I'm missing something.

As you can see the value of ifAdminStatus for interface with index 20 is 1

...

```
Router(tcl)#snmp_getone Public ifAdminStatus.20
{<obj oid='ifAdminStatus.20' val='1'/>}
```

...

But I cannot get it with an If statement. Tested following syntaxes but did not succeed

...

```
Router(tcl)#
Router(tcl)#if {snmp_getone Public ifAdminStatus.20 ==1 } {puts "Value=1"}
syntax error in expression "snmp_getone Public ifAdminStatus.20 ==1 "
Router(tcl)#
Router(tcl)#if {'snmp_getone Public ifAdminStatus.20' ==1 } {puts "Value=1"}
syntax error in expression "'snmp_getone Public ifAdminStatus.20' ==1 "
Router(tcl)#if {[snmp_getone Public ifAdminStatus.20] ==1 } {puts "Value=1"}
```

...

I just like to have 1 returned if the value is 1. Then I should extend it to all ports and make array of interfaces, making actions, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this

```
snmp_getone Public ifAdminStatus.20
```

returns this

```
{<obj oid='ifAdminStatus.20' val='1'/>}
```

When you write

```
if {[snmp_getone Public ifAdminStatus.20] == _something_} { ...
```

then `_something_` will not be `"1"`.

You'll have to parse the result of the snmp_getone command to extract the value of the `val` attribute. Perhaps, quick and dirty:

```
set status [snmp_getone Public ifAdminStatus.20]
regexp {val='(.+?)'} $status -> val
if {$val == 1} {...
```

Comment: If the results are XML, [tDOM](http://tdom.org/index.html/dir?ci=trunk) is superb for parsing it.

Comment: Thanks it works but would you please tell me how this regexp is working : regexp {val='(.+?)'} and how does it extract #value – M. Ganji 1 min ago